# how to use date value from input type='date' ? only JS

Tags: javascript, date, input

Here is the code to set 'start date' and 'end date', and I haven't found how to get 'picked date' value from `input type='date'`.

If somebody knows, please help.

```js
function setPeriod() {
  var startDate = document.getElementById('startDate').value;
  var endDate = document.getElementById('endDate').value;
  
  
  console.log(startDate);
  console.log(endDate);
}
```

```html
<div class='calendar'>   
  <table border='1px solid black'>
    <thead>
      <tr>
        <th colspan='2'>
          Set period
        </th>
      </tr>
    </thead>
    <tbody>
      <tr>
        <th>
          Start Date
        </th>
        <td>
          <input type='date' id='startDate'>
        </td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <th>
          End Date
        </th>
        <td>
          <input type='date' id='endDate'>
        </td>
      </tr>
    </tbody>
  </table>
  <button onclick='setPeriod();'>설정</button>
</div>
```

Comment: You have to get the `.value` of the `<input>` elements and then construct Date instances from the values.

Comment: I edited referred to your advice, and console.log(edate); still does not work.

Comment: Your code is not even running. It should be `onclick='setPeriod()'`.

Answer (score 1):

Simply use **valueAsDate**

```js
const startDate = document.getElementById('startDate')
    , endDate   = document.getElementById('endDate')
    , options   = { weekday: 'long', year: 'numeric', month: 'long', day: 'numeric' }
    , dayMillis = 1000 * 60 * 60 * 24
    , diffDays  = (d1,d2) => Math.ceil(Math.abs(d2 - d1) / dayMillis )
    ;


function getPeriod()
  {
  console.log( 'start date =', startDate.valueAsDate.toLocaleDateString('en-EN', options) );
  console.log( 'end date   =', endDate.valueAsDate.toLocaleDateString('de-DE', options) );
  console.log( 'days between ->', diffDays(startDate.valueAsDate, endDate.valueAsDate)  );
  }
```

```html
<div class='calendar'>   
  <table border='1px solid black'>
    <thead>
      <tr> <th colspan='2'> Set period </th> </tr>
    </thead>
    <tbody>
      <tr>
        <th> Start Date </th>
        <td> <input type='date' id='startDate'> </td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <th> End Date </th>
        <td> <input type='date' id='endDate'> </td>
      </tr>
    </tbody>
  </table>
  <button onclick='getPeriod()'>get periods</button>
</div>
```

Comment: @RobG on which line / instruction ?

Answer (score 0):

I made this simple script for you, hope it helps!
And also I've corrected the call mistake in the `onclick` attribute it must be `setPeriod()`

```js
function setPeriod() {
  var startDate = document.getElementById('startDate').value;
      startDate = startDate.split("-");
  
  var endDate = document.getElementById('endDate').value;
      endDate = endDate.split("-");
  
  
  var sDate = new Date();
      sDate.setYear(startDate[0]);
      sDate.setMonth(startDate[1]-1);
      sDate.setDate(startDate[2]);

  var eDate = new Date();
      eDate.setYear(endDate[0]);
      eDate.setMonth(endDate[1]-1);
      eDate.setDate(endDate[2]);
 
  
  console.log(sDate);
  console.log(eDate);
}
```

```html
<div class='calendar'>   
  <table border='1px solid black'>
    <thead>
      <tr>
        <th colspan='2'>
          Set period
        </th>
      </tr>
    </thead>
    <tbody>
      <tr>
        <th>
          Start Date
        </th>
        <td>
          <input type='date' id='startDate'>
        </td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <th>
          End Date
        </th>
        <td>
          <input type='date' id='endDate'>
        </td>
      </tr>
    </tbody>
  </table>
  <button onclick='setPeriod()'>설정</button>
</div>
```